# I am wondering what address do you use to call flashloan?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, erc-20, aave, arbitrage

I am using this address to call flashloan 0x65aFADD39029741B3b8f0756952C74678c9cEC93 but I get Gas estimation failed error please let me know if you use another address and successfully call the request flash loan function, thanks

Comment: What network are you using? mainnet, sepolia, layer2, .. What code are you using to request the flashloan? There are several services that provide flash loans.

Comment: Goeril, I am using the aave flashloan contract

Comment: The address looks like an USDC clone contract. It is Goerli so you could use if it works.

Comment: So I got USDC from aave faucet, but is there any specific USDC to use in Goerli?

Comment: Usually, in testnet there aren't official token addresses. Some projects deploy their own copies and leave them for anyone to use them. If that address works for you then it should be fine. Otherwise you can deploy your own copy for testing purposes.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? im trying to get aave USDC but it only gives me ETH usdc on goerli network. Do you knoow were i can get aave USDC?